# can't find custom embedded code on weebly

Tags: weebly

I've added some custom javascript to my weebly site using the EMBED button.

Now, I want to change it but can't get back to it in the weebly editor.

How can I find my old custom code?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it. I just needed to slowly move my mouse over the body of the page and "edit embedded code" appeared.